# Compare XML data to String

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012, compare

I have a table that houses a bunch of data in an XML field.  I can get to the data and display what I need in the select statement, but I also need to use that to compare to another table that houses a translation I am trying to do.  Is there a way to compare the value being returned from the XML data to a string value that exists in another table?

The code in my select to return the XML data is:

```
prv.reported_attributes.value('(/row[@ATTRIBUTE="FIELD"][1])/@VALUE', 'varchar(5)')
```

I need to compare that text output to another table, but I keep getting NULL like the values I am trying to compare do not match.  I have confirmed they do in fact have matches.

Comment: You added the "sql"-tag to your question. Is this related to the question and if so can you specify which version?

Comment: Im using sql server 2012

Comment: to get good answer please provide sample input and sample output you want to get